# Get the shortest path between two linked object

Tags: c#

I have a "Contact" object which contains a list called "Linked" containing the "Contact" linked to it.

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> Linked { get; set; }
}
```

For example, Contact "A" has 3 linked contacts: B, C and D.
As the links are made in both directions each time, B, C and D all have A in their "Linked" contacts.
B can then have E as a contact, and so on. There is no limit.

I have to make an algo which takes a starting contact and an ending contact as a parameter and which finds the shortest path that links them.

The result must be in the form: A > B > F > H > X, if I have to find the path that goes from A to X. We must therefore find all the steps of the path in the result.

I've tried a lot of stuff (recursion, ...) but it's still getting stuck somewhere.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm perhaps? There's a few C# implementations online, for example: https://www.csharpstar.com/dijkstra-algorithm-csharp/

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1221034/Pathfinding-Algorithms-in-Csharp

Answer (score 2):

Dijkstra's algorithm is probably what you are looking for.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

> Dijkstra's algorithm (/ˈdaɪkstrəz/ DYKE-strəz) is an algorithm for finding the shortest paths between nodes in a graph, which may represent, for example, road networks. It was conceived by computer scientist Edsger W. Dijkstra in 1956 and published three years later.[4][5][6]

It should be relatively straight forward to find examples in your given language. Here is one in C#, stolen from [programmingalgorithms.com](https://www.programmingalgorithms.com/algorithm/dijkstra%27s-algorithm/)

```cs
private static int MinimumDistance(int[] distance, bool[] shortestPathTreeSet, int verticesCount)
{
    int min = int.MaxValue;
    int minIndex = 0;

    for (int v = 0; v < verticesCount; ++v)
    {
        if (shortestPathTreeSet[v] == false && distance[v] <= min)
        {
            min = distance[v];
            minIndex = v;
        }
    }

    return minIndex;
}

void Print(int[] distances, int sourceNode, Dictionary<int, int> shortestPathTree, int verticesCount)
{
    Console.Write("Vertex\t\tDistance from Source\t\tPath\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < verticesCount; i++)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        if (sourceNode != i)
        {
            builder = GetFormattedPath(builder, sourceNode, i, shortestPathTree);
        }

        Console.Write(i + "\t\t" + distances[i] + "\t\t" + builder.Append(i).ToString() + "\n");
    }
}

private StringBuilder GetFormattedPath(StringBuilder builder, int sourceNode, int destinationNode, Dictionary<int, int> shortestPathTree)
{
    var previousNode = shortestPathTree[destinationNode];

    if (previousNode != sourceNode)
    {
        GetFormattedPath(builder, sourceNode, previousNode, shortestPathTree);
    }

    builder.Append(previousNode).Append(", ");

    return builder;
}

public static void Dijkstra(int[,] graph, int source, int verticesCount)
{
    int[] distance = new int[verticesCount];
    bool[] shortestPathTreeSet = new bool[verticesCount];
    Dictionary<int, int> shortestPathTree = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < verticesCount; ++i)
    {
        distance[i] = int.MaxValue;
        shortestPathTreeSet[i] = false;
    }

    distance[source] = 0;

    for (int count = 0; count < verticesCount - 1; ++count)
    {
        int u = MinimumDistance(distance, shortestPathTreeSet, verticesCount);
        shortestPathTreeSet[u] = true;

        for (int v = 0; v < verticesCount; ++v)
            if (!shortestPathTreeSet[v] && Convert.ToBoolean(graph[u, v]) && distance[u] != int.MaxValue && distance[u] + graph[u, v] < distance[v])
            {   
              distance[v] = distance[u] + graph[u, v];
              shortestPathTree[v] = u;
            }
    }

    Print(distance, source, shortestPathTree, verticesCount);
}
```

It would then be used like so:

```cs
int[,] graph = {
    { 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0 },
    { 4, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0 },
    { 0, 8, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2 },
    { 0, 0, 7, 0, 9, 14, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 4, 0, 10, 0, 2, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 2, 0, 1, 6 },
    { 8, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 7 },
    { 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0 }
};

Dijkstra(graph, 0, 9);
```

The example above consist of 9 nodes, and the distance to each of the other nodes. If it has 0, there is no connection. In your case, there is no weight - so either there is a connection (1), or there isn't (0).

You have to change the algorithm to take in a list of contacts, instead of a two dimensional array. Try to think of the two dimensional array as a list of lists - very similar to a list of contacts, where each contact has another list of contacts.

Lets for example create a simple contacts list and their contacts:

- Peter can contact Mary
- Mary can contact Peter and John
- John can contact Mary

This would be represented something like this in a two dimensional array:

```cs
int[,] contacts = new int[]
{
    { 0, 1, 0 }, //Peter: Peter no, Mary yes, John no
    { 1, 0, 1 }, //Mary: Peter yes, Mary no, John yes
    { 0, 1, 0 }  //John: Peter no, Mary yes, John no
}
```

You would also have to modify the algorithm to keep track of the current path. That should be a relatively straight forward change.

Hope that it helps!